# navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES does not call viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

If I run, within IOS not swift,

```
[[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] viewWillAppear:YES]
```

it calls viewWillAppear on the previous VC.

I need to jump back to the root VC and have that ViewWillAppear called; however,

`[[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] viewWillAppear:YES]` gives me a coding error.

Is there a way to do this without applicationWillEnterForeground: and applicationDidBecomeActive: methods in my appDelegate

I have tried within init

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                   selector:@selector(willEnterForeground:)
                                       name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                     object:nil];
```

And in body

```
-(void) willEnterForeground:(Notification*)NotificationCenter
{
(self viewWillAppear:YES);
}
```

This doesn't seem to call viewWillAppear either.

Comment: *"gives me a coding error"* -- what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems quite incorrect...

First, you should never call `viewWillAppear` - that is the system notifying your controller that the view will appear.

Second, just calling:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

will navigate to the previous view controller in the stack, or:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

will navigate to the Root view controller.

In both cases, `viewWillAppear` ***is*** called by the system when the view, well, will appear.

Comment: Thats true under the previous OS (and how my code read before), but not the newest.  What versions are you running?

Comment: Did a quick test on various devices / simulators... iOS 12.x to 13.3 ... `viewWillAppear` is called in the "navigated-to" view controller. Here's a link to an example project on GitHub  - each time you navigate to a VC, it will log the `viewWillAppear` call. https://github.com/DonMag/WillAppearTest

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running?  As I said before, my code used to just navigate back to the previous or root VC and the viewWillAppear was called but not since I updated to Catalina and the newest Xcode.  If I attach an actual device running either iOS 10 or 13, it operates correctly as before, but if I run the app using the newest simulators, it does not call the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.  There are other threads on this issue now.

Comment: I created that GitHub project with Xcode 11.3 and iPhone 8 simulator 13.3 running on Catalina. When you run my example app, do you not see the `viewWillAppear` print statements in debug console?

Comment: Hi DonMag.  Working from home so I can't get to my dev computer at the moment.  Does your sample code contain push views and pop views to show previous or root view controllers?  That is when the viewWillAppear fails to be called.  When the original VC appears, the method is called, but when I pop back to the root or previous VC it does not.  Thats why I started adding viewWillAppear:boolean to the pop view command.  That does work on the new simulators but without the viewWillAppear:boolean it works on the actual device running 13.3 but not on the simulator.

Comment: Don, I am not using swift.  Apparently it works correctly under swift but not under xcode I have been using for sometime.  Can not explain it.

Comment: @cavuco - the example project I put up on GitHub is done with Objective-C (***not*** Swift).

Comment: I saw storyboard layout and assumed you were using swift.  I created the navigationcontroller from code not the IB.  I have implemented the modalpresentationstyle.fullscreen to address this persons solution, which is exactly my issue too https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/411255#411255 and I still am not calling the viewWillAppear.  Perhaps with Apple's IOS change to 13 this is becoming too difficult.  I am implementing the AppDelegate for my NavController.   I put breaks on all my VC viewWillAppear and they are only called on the initial view, not when I pop back to them.

Comment: Code or Storyboard is inconsequential - did you grab the example I put up and take a look at what it's doing? Also, you now comment *"modalpresentationstyle.fullscreen"* ... but that's the first mention of it. Are you taking about *presenting* a VC and `viewWillAppear` not being called when the modal is dismissed? Or are you still working with a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, the logic of what you are doing is almost exactly as I have. I have both methods in play on my app.  I pushViewController and when I return using popViewController it is not calling viewWillAppear.   I am also using NavController and that behaves the same way. I should not be modal but that is one of the suggestions (see link above) that I tried.  Every thread seems to address that.  This is very frustrating aas teh app works perfectly on an actual device and on simulators prior to the newest ones.

Comment: @cavuco - without seeing what else you are doing, it's really tough to try to figure out. I updated my GitHub repo with a "CodeBased" example... the only Storyboard is the LaunchScreen. Let me know if that fails to call `viewWillAppear`: https://github.com/DonMag/WillAppearTest

Comment: I did DL your codebased git and it works fine. Thank you very much.  We are using an app that was developed and updated over several years.  What I am trying to understand is how an app that works on older IOS and xcode on both devices and simulators but ceases to work on new simulators under IOS 13.3 but continues to work on the actual devices.  I can not completely rewrite the app to match your very clean code.   I did notice that you reference the popToRoot within an included .h file instead of within the individual VC such as the 1st,2nd, 3rd VC.  Did u go to forum link above

Comment: *"I am trying to understand is how an app that works on older IOS and xcode on both devices and simulators but ceases to work on new simulators..."* --- well, not trying to sound trite, but if a "clean" example works, and your code doesn't, it would appear the issue lies somewhere else in your code. It *could* be related to your reference of "modalpresentationstyle.fullscreen" but as we have been talking only about navigation controller, I have no way of knowing. As to the popToRoot in a .h file, that is only related to subclassing the controllers, rather than duplicating code.

Comment: @cavuco - if you can put together a [mcve] I will take a look at it.

Comment: I also am using an appdelegate for each VC (for persistence).

Comment: So each pushViewController looks like this:  AppDelegate *del =(AppDelegate *[[UIApplication SharedApplication] delegate];    [self.navigationController pushviewController:[del modeVC]animated:YES];